# MySQL unique user ID trigger using substring concatenated columns

Tags: mysql, triggers, unique

I'm trying to create a trigger to generate a unique ID using the first two characters of the persons first name, and the first three characters of their last name. 
This is the error I'm currently working through:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@firstID varchar(2), DECLARE @lastID varchar (3), DECLARE @newID varchar (5); ' at line 3
```

I also do not think I can just add two (string) variables by just using '+' but `CONCAT` was not working either. Please help!

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE TRIGGER EID BEFORE INSERT ON edrstaff FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE @firstID varchar(2),
DECLARE @lastID varchar (3),
DECLARE @newID varchar (5);

SET @firstID = (
SELECT SUBSTRING(fname, FROM 1 FOR 2))
FROM edrstaff
WHERE fname = new.fname)

SET @lastID = (SELECT SUBSTRING(lname, FROM 1 FOR 3))

FROM edrstaff
WHERE lname = new.lname); 

SET @newID = @firstID + @lastID; 

END @@
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CREATE TRIGGER EID 
BEFORE INSERT ON edrstaff 
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.id = CONCAT(LEFT(NEW.fname, 2), LEFT(NEW.lname, 3));
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33cfdb/1)**

Comment: Thank you for your response! but I got this error #1054 - Unknown column 'lname' in 'NEW'

Comment: You're welcome. Please post table `edrstaff` structure (preferable in a form of `CREATE TABLE` statement) and an `INSERT` statement that caused that error.

Comment: @Louisa Do you need more help with your question?